# Почему IO имеет побочный эффект

Tags: haskell

Сразу скажу, Haskell пока не изучал. Просто читал о нем, и насколько понял, чистые функции - те которые не изменяют глобального состояния. А что изменяет IO? Просто ведь выводит сообщение.

Comment: выводит куда? :-)

Comment: Чистая функция общается с внешним миром только через аргументы (на вход) и возвращаемое значение (на выход). Причем при одних и тех же входных значениях должно быть одно и то же возвращаемое значение. Условная функция PRINT общается с внешним миром еще через вывод на экран, это и есть ее побочный эффект. Функция INPUT наоборот получает значения не из аргументов, а из внешнего мира (с клавиатуры), причем при разном вводе со стороны пользователя (но при одних и тех же аргументах) должна выдавать разные значения, что априори делает ее не чистой функцией.

Comment: Она изменяет состояние вашего монитора - там пиксели по-другому светиться начинают.

Comment: Допустим у меня код на С
'int fun(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b
}'  
Он же тоже будет возвращать  одно и тоже значение, если а и b те же.
Да и зачем тогда язык, который по правилам своей парадигмы не может вывести сообщение на экран(не в обиду Haskell давно им интересуюсь, просто так вопрос звучит лучше).

Comment: @ZX-SPECTRUM, чистые функции можно реализовать не только на Haskell, это вообще математическая концепция по сути. Ну и на экран на Haskell конечно же можно выводить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IO` это не функция, это как раз изменяемое состояние.

Сообщения выводят функции, такие, как `putChar`. Классическую функцию `putchar` из языка C нельзя назвать чистой, поскольку она обладает побочным эффектом, а конкретно, изменяет состояние потока вывода.

Использовать такую функцию в чистом функциональном языке нельзя, чему есть несколько причин. Одна из них заключается в том, что, например, в Хаскелле применяется *нормальный*, он же *ленивый* порядок вычисления выражений, поэтому такие функции как `putchar` просто не будут вызываться. Они ничего не возвращают и их результаты нигде в вычислениях не используются, так что компилятор их просто игнорирует.

Для того, чтобы сделать такие функции чистыми, применяется своеобразный трюк. Так как функция меняет состояние, мы можем сделать это изменение явным, передавая старое состояние в качестве параметра и возвращая новое состояние как результат функции. Если вызов классической функции `putchar` выглядит так:

```
putchar('F');
putchar('o');
putchar('o');
```

то вызов чистой `putchar` мог бы выглядеть так:

```
stdout_state s1;
stdout_state s2 = putchar(s1, 'F');
stdout_state s3 = putchar(s2, 'o');
stdout_state s4 = putchar(s3, 'o');
```

Здесь `stdout_state` — выдуманный тип, который как бы хранит состояние потока вывода. Такая версия функции `putchar` «становится чистой», потому что если мы будем много раз вызывать её со старым состоянием `s1` и символом `'F'`, она всегда будет возвращать новое состояние `s2`.

Я написал «становится чистой» в кавычках, поскольку в действительности нет никакой возможности сохранить и повторно использовать состояние `s1`: как только мы вывели символ, он появляется в консоли.

Но с точки зрения теории (и компилятора) функция `putchar` действительно становится чистой. Во-первых, у нас появляется результат вычисления, а именно конечное состояние `s4`. Если есть результат, будут вызваны и функции, чтобы его вычислить.

Чтобы получить `s4`, сначала надо вычислить `s3`, а для неё, в свою очередь — `s2`, поэтому вызов `s2 = putchar(s1, 'F')` будет самым первым, `s3 = putchar(s2 'o')` — вторым, и `s4 = putchar(s3, 'o')` — третьим.

Возникает вопрос, как провернуть тот же самый трюк с функциями, которые возвращают значение, например, с `getchar`? Такая функция должна получать в качестве параметра старое состояние и возвращаться новое состояние и результат:

```
struct stoud_state_ch
{
    stdout_state s;
    char ch;
};

stdout_state s1;
stdout_state_ch r1 = getchar(s1);
stdout_state_ch r2 = getchar(r1.s);
stdout_state s2 = putchar(r2.s, r1.ch);
stdout_state s3 = putchar(s2, r2.ch);
```

Код получился громоздким, но я намеренно использовал старый добрый C, потому что он позволяет разглядеть детали. Здесь мы читаем из входного потока два символа, а потом выводим их в выходной поток, используя чистые версии функций `getchar` и `putchar`.

Мы видим, что придётся заводить новый тип `stoud_state_T` для каждого возвращаемого типа `T`. Например, для чистой версии функции `gets` нам бы потребовалась структура:

```
struct stoud_state_str
{
    stdout_state s;
    char *str;
};
```

На C++ мы могли бы воспользоваться шаблонами, чтобы упростить описание состояний с результатом:

```
template<typename T>
struct stdout_state_res
{
    stdout_state s;
    T res;
};
```

Тогда чистые функции `getchar` и `gets` можно было бы описать так:

```
stdout_state_res<char> getchar(stdout_state s);
stdout_state_res<char*> gets(stdout_state s);

. . .

stdout_state s1;
stdout_state_res<char> r1 = getchar(s1);
stdout_state_res<char*> r2 = gets(r1.s);
stdout_state_res<char> r3 = getchar(r2.s);
```

Мы видим здесь асимметрию между параметром функции и её результатом: на вход мы получаем состояние, а возвращаем состояние и значение. Чтобы сделать код единообразным, мы можем на вход получать результат предыдущих вызовов `getchar` или `gets`:

```
template<typename T>
stdout_state_res<char> getchar(stdout_state_res<T> s);

template<typename T>
stdout_state_res<char*> gets(stdout_state_res<T> s);
```

C++ не позволяет использовать тип `void` в качестве параметра шаблона, но давайте предположим, что это ограничение не действует. Тогда мы могли бы описать чистую версию функции `putchar`, которая возвращает состояние и пустой результат типа `void`:

```
template<typename T>
stdout_state_res<void> putchar(stdout_state_res<T> s, char ch);
```

Имея такие определения, мы могли бы написать чистый код, который читает из входного потока два символа и записывает их в выходной поток:

```
stdout_state_res<void> r1;
stdout_state_res<char> r2 = getchar(r1);
stdout_state_res<char> r3 = getchar(r2);
stdout_state_res<void> r4 = putchar(r3, r2.res);
stdout_state_res<void> r5 = putchar(r4, r3.res);
```

Функции стали выглядеть симметрично, а код — красиво. Возвращаясь к Хаскеллю, можно провести аналогию между типами `stdout_state_res<T>` и `IO a`.

Они не полностью соответствуют друг другу, в частности, состояние не передается между функциями в явном виде, а прячется внутрь комбинирующей функции `>>=`, поэтому у `getChar` и `putChar` нет параметра `state`:

```
getChar :: IO Char
putChar :: Char -> IO ()
```

Тем не менее, мы видим, что в первом случае возвращается что-то похожее на `stdout_state_res<char>`, а во втором — на `stdout_state_res<void>`.

Тип `IO` также параметризован, как и `stdout_state_res`, поэтому может хранить результаты разного типа. Вместо `void` в Хаскелле применяется тип `unit` и `IO` без результатов обозначается как `IO ()`.

Поскольку состояние в явном виде вынесено в `IO`, функции `getChar` и `putChar` в Хаскелле являются чистыми в математическом смысле. При этом позволяют работать с такой непредсказуемой штукой, как потоки ввода-вывода.

Comment: Как вообще изобрели правило про отсутствие побочных эффектов и зачем?

Comment: @ZX-SPECTRUM, Классические математические функции вроде арифметического умножения, синуса, извлечения квадратного корня — чистые. Именно такие функции и рассматриваются в лямбда-исчислении, и основные выводы делаются относительно них. В частности, вывод о том, что порядок вычисления операндов функции не имеет значения: если функция может быть вычислена, результат будет одинаков. Состояние важно для *машины Тьюринга*, где записи на лентах могут быть переписаны.

Comment: В любом случае мой вопрос мог показаться оскорбительным. Простите. Но все же, если в основе лямбда-исчисления лежит такие заключения, почему решили сделать такой язык для программирования? Просто обязательно должны быть преимущества.

Comment: @ZX-SPECTRUM, [because it's f*ng awesome!](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20101209.gif) Если серьезно, то лябмда-исчисление - это альтернативная модель вычислений по сравнению с машиной Тьюринга (с которой можно сравнить работу императивных языков). Советую все-таки продолжить изучения Haskell, это позволит по иному взглянуть и на "мэйнстримовые" императивные языки программирования.

Comment: @ZX-SPECTRUM У вас три или четыре вопрос замаскированы в одном, поэтому кратко я вряд ли смогу ответить. Если только про преимущества: чистота функций позволяет проводить компилятору очень агрессивную оптимизацию. Даже компилятор C, оптимизируя `a + b + c - b` оставит только часть `a + c`, потому что сложение и вычитание это *чистые* функции. Компилятор Haskell не вычисляет выражения, если их значение не нужно (ленивые вычисления), а когда оно нужно, вычисляет его только один раз (мемоизация). Чистые функции очень хорошо параллелизуются. Их корректность доказывается гораздо проще.

Comment: А может ли язык быть чистым без ленивых вычислений? То есть благодаря этому IO приходится еще и в монаду закручивать?

Comment: Хаскелль чистый функциональный язык и там реализованы ленивые вычисления. Другие популярные языки скорее мультипарадигменные, то есть там есть средства императивного программирования, не основанные на монадах. Я так думаю, не обязательно, чтобы чистый язык был обязательно ленивым, но сходу не вспомню чистого не-ленивого языка. Что касается монад, то благодаря синтаксическому сахару в Хаскелль они выглядят очень просто. Код на Хаскелле ничуть не сложнее кода на C выше.

Answer (score 1):

Чистая функция должна общаться с внешним миром **только** через аргументы (**только** на вход) и возвращаемое значение (на выход).

По определению [чистая функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) должна подчиняться двум условиям:

1. должна быть детерминированной (при одних и тех же входных данных должна возвращать одни и те же значения);
2. не обладает побочными эффектами.

С этой точки зрения любая классическая функция ввода нарушает первое условие (на вход, например, передается число - хэндлер устройства (все время один и тот же), а вывод разный).

Классическая функция вывода нарушает второе условие - она влияет на внешний мир каким-то образом кроме как через возвращаемое значение. Любое действие типа записи в глобальную перменную/буфер/массив, запись на внешнее устройство, вывод на экран, печать на бумаге, мигание лампочкой, издавание звука и т.д. - являются побочными эффектами функции. Кстати, модификация переданного на вход функции объекта тоже является побочным эффектом.